# Java pdfbox library for Rectangle Rotation

Tags: java, pdfbox, affinetransform

Trying to rotate the rectangle using pdfbox libraries based on fabric json, but x-co-ordinate & y-co-ordinate are not showing in correct position.

code below:

```
public void drawRectangle(PDPageContentStream contentStream, PDPage page, JSONObject props) throws IOException {

        String originX = (String) props.get("originX");
        String originY = (String) props.get("originY");
        Double left = (Double) props.get(originX);
        Double top = (Double) props.get(originY);
        Double width = (Double) props.get("width");
        Double hight = (Double) props.get("height");

        
        String fillColor = (String) props.get("fill"); // "#B3B3B3";
        String strokeColor = null;
        if (hight != 1.0) {
            strokeColor = (String) props.get("stroke"); // "#000000";
        }
        Double strokeWidth = (Double) props.get("strokeWidth"); // 0.0f;
       
        String strokeLineCap = (String) props.get("strokeLineCap"); // "butt";
        String strokeLineJoin = (String) props.get("strokeLineJoin"); // "miter";
        Double strokeMitterLimit = (Double) props.get("strokeMiterLimit");
        
        
        String fillRule = (String) props.get("fillRule"); // "nonzero";
        contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(Color.decode(fillColor));
        if (hight != 1.0) {
            contentStream.setStrokingColor(Color.decode(strokeColor));
        }
        contentStream.setLineWidth(strokeWidth.floatValue());
        contentStream.setLineCapStyle(
                "butt".equalsIgnoreCase(strokeLineCap) ? 0 : ("round".equalsIgnoreCase(strokeLineCap) ? 1 : 2));
        contentStream.setLineJoinStyle(
                "miter".equalsIgnoreCase(strokeLineJoin) ? 0 : ("round".equalsIgnoreCase(strokeLineCap) ? 1 : 2));
        contentStream.setMiterLimit(strokeMitterLimit.floatValue());

        Double scaleX = (Double) props.get("scaleX"); // 1.0f;//must be minimum 1
        if (scaleX <= 1) {
            scaleX = (Double) 1.0;
        }
        Double scaleY = (Double) props.get("scaleY"); // 1.0f;// must be minimum 1
        if (scaleY <= 1) {
            scaleY = (Double) 1.0;
        }
        double angle = (double) props.get("angle"); // 0.0d; 
         
        PDRectangle cropBox = page.getCropBox(); 
        float tx = (cropBox.getLowerLeftX() + cropBox.getUpperRightX()) / 2; 
        float ty = (cropBox.getLowerLeftY() + cropBox.getUpperRightY()) / 2;
                   
        contentStream.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(tx, ty));
        contentStream.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(360-angle), 0, 0)); 
        contentStream.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(-tx, -ty));
                    
        contentStream.addRect(left.floatValue(), page.getMediaBox().getHeight()-top.floatValue() - hight.floatValue(), 
                   width.floatValue(), hight.floatValue());
           
        
        if ("nonzero".equals(fillRule)) {
            contentStream.fillAndStroke();
        } else {
            contentStream.fillAndStrokeEvenOdd();
        }
}
```

my sample fabric json:

```
{
        "type": "rect",
        "pos": 3,       
        "tag": "",
        "version": "4.3.1",
        "originX": "left",
        "originY": "top",
        "left": 550.6,
        "top": 632.35,
        "width": 71.26,
        "height": 99.51,
        "fill": "#B3B3B3",
        "stroke": "#000000",
        "strokeWidth": 0.0,
        "strokeLineCap": "butt",
        "strokeDashOffset": 0.0,
        "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
        "strokeMiterLimit": 4.0,
        "scaleX": 1.0,
        "scaleY": 1.0,
        "angle": 111.31,
        "flipX": false,
        "flipY": false,
        "opacity": 1.0,
        "visible": true,
        "backgroundColor": "",
        "fillRule": "nonzero",
        "paintFirst": "fill",
        "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
        "skewX": 0.0,
        "skewY": 0.0,
        "lockMovementX": false,
        "lockMovementY": false,
        "lockScalingX": false,
        "lockScalingY": false,
        "lockUniScaling": false,
        "lockRotation": false,
        "lockObject": false,
        "fillColor": {
            "id": 0,
            "cyan": 0,
            "magenta": 0,
            "yellow": 0,
            "black": 30,
            "tint": 100.0,
            "shade": 0.0,
            "name": "C=0 M=0 Y=0 K=30",
            "isTransparent": false,
            "isSpotColor": false
        },
        "strokeColor": {
            "id": 0,
            "cyan": 0,
            "magenta": 0,
            "yellow": 0,
            "black": 100,
            "tint": 100.0,
            "shade": 0.0,
            "name": "C=0 M=0 Y=0 K=100",
            "isTransparent": false,
            "isSpotColor": false
        },
        "rx": 0.0,
        "ry": 0.0,
        "absolutePositioned": false,
        "inverted": false
    }
```

and tried different ways as mentioned in stackoverflow, nothing seems to be working. I appreciate any help on that.

Comment: `not showing in correct position` please tell what you were expecting and what happened instead. Be aware that PDF coordinates start from the bottom.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thank you for the quick response, my input page with rectangle angle in degrees, actual pdf and expected pdf.               https://drive.google.com/file/d/13H-S-v1Uxn8wUVkGfW8cZHhXmQ8HSVaX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is more a problem in knowing how to play with affine transforms. I'm not very fast at this so I won't work on this one; what I usually do with these problems is to visualize it by holding a piece of paper and rotating it, then doing the moves (translations), and testing whether it works or not. You should improve the question by reducing it and throw out all that isn't relevant (e.g. the JoinStyle)